# View controllers not being deallocated

Tags: ios, view

I have 2 controllers InitViewController and SettingsViewController. Each view has a button that calls another view:

**InitViewController**

```
@interface InitViewController : UIViewController
    - (IBAction)loadSettings:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation InitViewController
    - (IBAction)loadSettings:(id)sender {
        SettingsViewController *vc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        vc = nil;
    }
@end
```

**SettingsViewController**

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController
    - (IBAction)back:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation SettingsViewController
    - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
        InitViewController *vc = [[InitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InitViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        vc = nil;
    }
@end
```

While I was profiling application and testing it by tapping buttons many times I saw that instances of InitViewController and SettingsViewController are still living => [image: PrintScreen]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see no `@autoreleasepool` around here...

Answer (score 5):

Your `SettingsViewController` doesn't return to the `InitViewController` that created it.  Instead, it creates a **new** instance of `InitViewController` and presents that.  So you end up with a stack of view controllers alternating between instances of `InitViewController` and `SettingsViewController`.

Since you never dismiss either type of view controller after presenting it, none of them can be deallocated.

Your `-[SettingsViewController back:]` action should dismiss itself rather than creating and presenting a new `InitViewController`.

```
@implementation SettingsViewController

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```